# ColdFusion not adding variable to url

Tags: coldfusion

Currently I'm in the works of creating a refrral system for my website, but somehow ColdFusion won't let me add a value to an URL.

When people sign up, they use a referral url which looks like this: /register/?referer=[name]. Followed by the following form:

```
<cfif IsDefined('URL.referer')>
<cfquery name="CheckRefer" datasource = "#DSN#">
SELECT username, ip_reg, look
FROM users
WHERE username='<cfoutput>#referer#</cfoutput>'
</cfquery> </cfif>

            <form id="register_step_two" method="post" action="complete.cfm<cfif #referer# is not 0 and #CheckRefer.RecordCount# is 1 and #CGI.REMOTE_ADDR# is not #CheckRefer.ip_reg#>?referer=<cfoutput>#referer#</cfoutput></cfif>">

                <input type="hidden" name="referer" id="referer" value="#referer#" />
                <input type="hidden" name="email" id="email" value="#form.email#" />
                <input type="hidden" name="bdday" id="bdday" value="#form.bdday#" />
                <input type="hidden" name="bdmonth" id="bdmonth" value="#form.bdmonth#" />
                <input type="hidden" name="bdyear" id="bdyear" value="#form.bdyear#">
                <input type="hidden" name="username" id="username" value="" />
                <input type="hidden" name="figure" id="figure" value="hr-834-61.hd-600-4.ch-3014-110.lg-3006-110-62.sh-3089-110.ca-3217-62-62,s-0.g-0.d-4.h-4.a-0,c201c1c1b7fceffd8d5e8f5204f593ef" />
                <input type="hidden" name="password" id="password" value="#form.password#" />
                <input type="submit" value="Registreer" id="register-button" onmousedown="this.style.backgroundColor='##ddd';" onmouseup="this.style.backgroundColor='##eee';" onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='##eee';" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='##fff';" disabled="disabled" />    
            </form>
```

But after clicking the submit button it redirects me to complete.cfm and not complete.cfm?referer=[name]. I don't know why this happens, because I'm using the same method on other pages. All the variables inside the  are defined...

For example: this form works perfectly fine (the code posted above is page 2 of 3 from my signup process, and this one underneed is the first one, page 3 is the complete.cfm).

```
<cfif IsDefined('URL.referer')>
<cfquery name="CheckRefer" datasource = "#DSN#">
SELECT username, ip_reg, look
FROM users
WHERE username='<cfoutput>#referer#</cfoutput>'
</cfquery> </cfif>
           <form id="register_step_one" method="post" action="step2.cfm<cfif        IsDefined('URL.referer') and URL.referer is not 0 and #CheckRefer.RecordCount# is 1 and #CGI.REMOTE_ADDR# is not #CheckRefer.ip_reg#>?referer=<cfoutput>#referer#</cfoutput></cfif>">
            <label for="email">Email</label><br />
            <input type="text" name="email" id="formemail" />
            <div class="errormsg display_none" id="habbo_name_message_box"> 
                <h3>Eoutmelding</h3> 
                Something went wrong..
            </div>
            <br /><br />
            <label for="password">New password</label><br /> 
            <input type="password" name="password" id="formpassword" />
            <br /><br>
            <label for="cpassword">Repeat password<label><br /> 
            <input type="password" name="cpassword" id="formcpassword" />
            <br /><br />
            Date of birth:<br />
            <select name="bdday" id="bdday" class="dateselector"><option value="">Dag</option><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option><option value="6">6</option><option value="7">7</option><option value="8">8</option><option value="9">9</option><option value="10">10</option><option value="11">11</option><option value="12">12</option><option value="13">13</option><option value="14">14</option><option value="15">15</option><option value="16">16</option><option value="17">17</option><option value="18">18</option><option value="19">19</option><option value="20">20</option><option value="21">21</option><option value="22">22</option><option value="23">23</option><option value="24">24</option><option value="25">25</option><option value="26">26</option><option value="27">27</option><option value="28">28</option><option value="29">29</option><option value="30">30</option><option value="31">31</option></select> <select name="bdmonth" id="bdmonth" class="dateselector"><option value="">Maand</option><option value="1">Januari</option><option value="2">Februari</option><option value="3">Maart</option><option value="4">April</option><option value="5">Mei</option><option value="6">Juni</option><option value="7">Juli</option><option value="8">Augustus</option><option value="9">September</option><option value="10">Oktober</option><option value="11">November</option><option value="12">December</option></select> <select name="bdyear" id="bdyear" class="dateselector"><option value="">Jaar</option><option value="2010">2010</option><option value="2009">2009</option><option value="2008">2008</option><option value="2007">2007</option><option value="2006">2006</option><option value="2005">2005</option><option value="2004">2004</option><option value="2003">2003</option><option value="2002">2002</option><option value="2001">2001</option><option value="2000">2000</option><option value="1999">1999</option><option value="1998">1998</option><option value="1997">1997</option><option value="1996">1996</option><option value="1995">1995</option><option value="1994">1994</option><option value="1993">1993</option><option value="1992">1992</option><option value="1991">1991</option><option value="1990">1990</option><option value="1989">1989</option><option value="1988">1988</option><option value="1987">1987</option><option value="1986">1986</option><option value="1985">1985</option><option value="1984">1984</option><option value="1983">1983</option><option value="1982">1982</option><option value="1981">1981</option><option value="1980">1980</option><option value="1979">1979</option><option value="1978">1978</option><option value="1977">1977</option><option value="1976">1976</option><option value="1975">1975</option><option value="1974">1974</option><option value="1973">1973</option><option value="1972">1972</option><option value="1971">1971</option><option value="1970">1970</option><option value="1969">1969</option><option value="1968">1968</option><option value="1967">1967</option><option value="1966">1966</option><option value="1965">1965</option><option value="1964">1964</option><option value="1963">1963</option><option value="1962">1962</option><option value="1961">1961</option><option value="1960">1960</option><option value="1959">1959</option><option value="1958">1958</option><option value="1957">1957</option><option value="1956">1956</option><option value="1955">1955</option><option value="1954">1954</option><option value="1953">1953</option><option value="1952">1952</option><option value="1951">1951</option><option value="1950">1950</option><option value="1949">1949</option><option value="1948">1948</option><option value="1947">1947</option><option value="1946">1946</option><option value="1945">1945</option><option value="1944">1944</option><option value="1943">1943</option><option value="1942">1942</option><option value="1941">1941</option><option value="1940">1940</option><option value="1939">1939</option><option value="1938">1938</option><option value="1937">1937</option><option value="1936">1936</option><option value="1935">1935</option><option value="1934">1934</option><option value="1933">1933</option><option value="1932">1932</option><option value="1931">1931</option><option value="1930">1930</option><option value="1929">1929</option><option value="1928">1928</option><option value="1927">1927</option><option value="1926">1926</option><option value="1925">1925</option><option value="1924">1924</option><option value="1923">1923</option><option value="1922">1922</option><option value="1921">1921</option><option value="1920">1920</option><option value="1919">1919</option><option value="1918">1918</option><option value="1917">1917</option><option value="1916">1916</option><option value="1915">1915</option><option value="1914">1914</option><option value="1913">1913</option><option value="1912">1912</option><option value="1911">1911</option><option value="1910">1910</option><option value="1909">1909</option><option value="1908">1908</option><option value="1907">1907</option><option value="1906">1906</option><option value="1905">1905</option><option value="1904">1904</option><option value="1903">1903</option><option value="1902">1902</option><option value="1901">1901</option><option value="1900">1900</option></select>
            <br />
            <div class="errormsg display_none" id="bd_err"><strong>Ongeldige geboortedatum.</strong></div><br>

            <input type="hidden" name="referer" id="referer" value="#referer#" />
            <input type="submit" id="reg_submit_button" value="Registreer" onmousedown="this.style.backgroundColor='#ddd';" onmouseup="this.style.backgroundColor='#eee';" onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#eee';" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#fff';" />
        </form>
```

Comment: You don't need to wrap your variables inside `##` in your `<cfif>` statement.  Does your form action contain the `?referer=foo` part in the URL in the generated HTML?

Comment: The #referer# gets the variable that is defined in the URL, so I don't think that I can remove it?

Comment: To clarify, I mean that `<cfif #referer# is not 0 and #CheckRefer.RecordCount# is 1 and #CGI.REMOTE_ADDR# is not #CheckRefer.ip_reg#>?referer=<cfoutput>#referer#</cfoutput></cfif>` can be written as `<cfif referer is not 0 and CheckRefer.RecordCount is 1 and CGI.REMOTE_ADDR is not CheckRefer.ip_reg>?referer=<cfoutput>#referer#</cfoutput></cfif>`

Comment: I see what you mean. But like I said it works on every other form that I'm using (added one to the main post), but except on this one. If I replace the `cfif` function with the one you provided me with it gives me plenty of errors and forces me to undo the changes :(

Comment: Output each value from your cfif statement. One of those values is returning false. Also you should consider reading up on style guidelines, you don't need # everywhere and you don't need the cfoutput in your cfquery

Comment: The cfif replacement duncan provided does not cause any errors, it merely simplifies the code by removing redundant characters. More significant than that though is the SQL injection and HTML injection that you're allowing by not parameterising/encoding the URL variable. (p.s. the correct spelling is "referrer")

Comment: Life is a lot easier if you deal with either the form scope or the url scope, but not both.  That url variable you are appending to your form action attribute could easily be a hidden form field.

Comment: You are passing the value of `referer` in the form already. why do you want to pass that same information in the URL? As Dan stated, mixing URL and FORM scope makes things more difficult.

Comment: And, yea, remove the `#` signs from within the `cfif`. Also, you do not need `cfoutput` inside of a `cfquery`. You should also be using `cfqueryparam` in your queries

Comment: I've managed to get it working with all of your feedback. Thanks a lot! Can't select any best answer because everything was posted in the comments, but thank you so much everyone ;)!